# How to set HTML value for taxonomy description field using entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I've set my taxonomy description field to taking a filtered text value. Using the UI, I can edit a taxonomy term, write some HTML, save, and when I view it I see the HTML rendered by my browser.

However when doing this:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('taxonomy_term', 123);
$wrapper->description->set('<p>My html</p>');
$wrapper->save();
```

And viewing the term's page, the description comes out with the html converted to entities, i.e. I see `<p>My html</p>` instead of a paragraph with `My html` as its content.

I notice that

```
$wrapper->description->value(); // <p>&lt;p&gtp;My html&lt;p&gt;</p>
```

Whereas if I load a term that I have edited with the UI, saving HTML to the description field,

```
$wrapper->description->value(); // <p>Some html</p>
```

I've looked at `$wrapper->description` and `$wrapper->value()->description` and there's no difference between a term with/without the correct/desired behaviour.

Also, I note that with normal fields, when you set a formatted text field you pass/get an array `[ 'format' => 'filtered', 'value' => '<p>the html</p>' ]` whereas here I only ever get a string.

Is this something peculiar to taxonomy terms (and is there a workaround or extra code I need)? Have I misunderstood something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered a [similar situation myself](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216417/programmatically-render-html-in-taxonomy-term-description) and it looks like you're choices are either [`taxonomy_term_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7.x) or to update the table directly via  [`db_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_update/7.x). The format property belongs to the term itself, rather than the Description property of the term. If you execute `$term->getPropertyInfo()` you'll see that the format property is not returned. Keep in mind that the Description is a property of the taxonomy entity, rather than a field, but doesn't seem to be accessible via EMW.

### taxonomy_term_save()

```
taxonomy_term_save((object)array(
  'tid' => $tid,
  'description' => $t($descriptions[$info['step']]),
  'format' => 'full_html',
  'vid' => $vocab->vid,
));
```

Comment: Thanks for this work around. Strange how the wrapper can't deal with this.