# Programmatically render HTML in taxonomy term description

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm facing an issue where I'm attempting to programmatically set the description property for a taxonomy term that includes HTML, but the HTML is being rendered as text, rather than being rendered into HTML elements, unless I manually access the term in a browser and save it.

### Example

```
taxonomy_term_save((object)array(
  'name' => $name,
  'description' => $t('<h5>My description.</h5><p>More info.</p>'),
  'vid' => $vocab->vid,
));
```

When I attempt to render the description, it appears as:

> `<h5>My description.</h5><p>More info.</p>`

However, if I then go to Structure > Taxonomy > My_Vocabulary > My_Term and simply save the term (without any edits), it will then render properly as:

> **My description.**
>
> More info.

I've also made a number of attempts to achieve this through an Entity Metadata Wrapper, but no luck (though I am admittedly not well versed on EMWs).

How can I programmatically force the description to correctly render the HTML without having to manually re-save it?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just on mobile so can't check - isn't there a `format` property can you set to `full_html`, or the name of another more permissive filter?

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no format property because Description is an entity property, rather than a field (corrections to any misunderstanding are welcome!).

Comment: @Clive, I take that back. I was so focused on the idea that the format property belonged to the Description that I didn't think to look at the term itself. There is indeed a format property that I completely overlooked as part of taxonomy_term_save(). Please post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Just got back to the computer and answered as it happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `taxonomy_term_data` table, which is the entity table for taxonomy terms, has a `format` column which stores the name of a filter to apply to the `description` when rendered.

It's available as a property on the entity, so you can use:

```
taxonomy_term_save((object)array(
  'name' => $name,
  'description' => $t('<h5>My description.</h5><p>More info.</p>'),
  'vid' => $vocab->vid,
  'format' => 'full_html',
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7.x) property:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$term->description = t('<pre><strong>Text</strong></pre>');
$term->format = 'full_html';
taxonomy_term_save($term);
```

Comment: this is also great information and I'm grateful for it! It just happens to be that Clive beat you to it. :-)

Comment: It's not about beating or losing, we all learn and help each other. Remember that you can always reward a good answer not only by accepting it but by up-voting it in either case ;) I up voted  Clive's answer while you didn't , see what I mean ?

Comment: Actually, I did upvote his answer (and yours), but my reputation is too puny to count. :/